# Question: I want to delete directory from my maven project when i am running mvn eclipse:clean

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing, testng

This is what I have added in my pom.xml under suite tag. But when i run mvn eclipse:clean it successfully deletes .project and .setting files but not my Report directory.

```
 <suite>
  ....
  <build>
  <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <directory>Reports</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
        </fileset>
     </filesets>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
</build>
.....
</suite>
```

Please suggest if I am putting the plugin tags at wrong places.

Comment: I recommend to think what this directory `Reports` is needed at the root level of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try below if it helps

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>auto-clean</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>some/relative/path</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your XML Tags, here is the valid XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<build>
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <filesets>
                  <fileset>
                     <directory>Reports</directory>
                     <includes>
                        <include>**</include>
                     </includes>
                     <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                  </fileset>
               </filesets>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: sorry its just typo i will update but still it didnt worked with closed tags